# stylelint rule to enforce use of predefined classes instead of css

Tags: css, reactjs, eslint, stylelint

I have defined common css classnames to re-use in multiple places, like

common.scss:

```css
.m-r-4 {margin-right: 4px}
.m-l-4 {margin-left: 4px}
.p-r-4 {padding-right: 4px}
.p-l-4 {padding-left: 4px}
```

Is there any stylelint plugin to give warning to use these classes instead of writing same css rules (ex: `margin-right: 4px`) in other css files ? The project uses React, Webpack and StyleLint

If there is no plugin for this, any links/tutorial that can help to develop plugin like this would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`property-disallowed-list`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/property-disallowed-list/) rule to disallow properties, and you can use a [custom message](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#message) to communicate your intent.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "property-disallowed-list": [
      ["/^margin/", "/^padding/"],
      {
        "message": "Use the appropriate utility class instead"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can then [turn off the rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/ignore-code/#within-files) in your `common.scss` file:

```
/* stylelint-disable property-disallowed-list */
.m-r-4 {margin-right: 4px}
.m-l-4 {margin-left: 4px}
.p-r-4 {padding-right: 4px}
.p-l-4 {padding-left: 4px}
```

Alternatively, you can [write a plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins) that [checks against the built-in rule](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins#stylelintutilscheckagainstrule), but not for the `common.scss` file by checking the filename before processing.